# Web Api - Mutex Per User

Tags: multithreading, asp.net-core, mutex, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an asp.net core Web Api application. 
In my application I have Web Api method which I want to prevent multi request from the same user to enter simultaneously. I don't mind request from different users to perform simultaneously.

I am not sure how to create the lock and where to put it. I thought about creating some kind of a dictionary which will contains the user id and perform the lock on the item but I don't think i'm getting it right. Also, what will happen if there is more than one server and there is a load balancer?

Example: 
Let assume each registered user can do 10 long task each month. I need to check for each user if he exceeded his monthly limit. If the user will send many simultaneously requests to the server, he might be allowed to perform more than 10 operations. I understand that I need to put a lock on the method but I do want to allow other users to perform this action simultaneously.

Comment: Define "simultaneously" as there's no way two requests will come at the same nanosecond. Do you want to throttle the users to N requests per second per user? Discard duplicate requests? Not handle a new request while an existing request for that user is still running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're asking for is fundamentally not how the Internet works. The HTTP and underlying IP protocols are stateless, meaning each request is supposed to run independent of any knowledge of what has occurred previously (or concurrently, as the case may be). If you're worried about excessive load, your best bet is to implement rate limiting/throttling tied to authentication. That way, once a user burns through their allotted requests, they're cut off. This will then have a natural side-effect of making the developers programming against your API more cautious about sending excessive requests.

Just to be a bit more thorough, here, the chief problem with the approach you're suggesting is that I know of no way it can be practically implemented. You can use something like `SemaphoreSlim` to create a lock, but that needs to be static so that the same instance is used for each request. Being static is going to limit your ability to use a dictionary of them, which is what you'll need for this. It can technically be done, I suppose, but you'd have to use a `ConcurrentDictionary` and even then, there's no guarantee of single-thread additions. So, concurrent requests for the same user could load concurrent semphaphores into it, which defeats the entire point. I suppose you could front-load the dictionary with a semphaphore for each user from the start, but that could become a huge waste of resources, depending on your user-base. Long and short, it's one of those things where when you're finding a solution this darn difficult, it's a good sign you're likely trying to do something you shouldn't be doing.

**EDIT**

After reading your example, I think this really just boils down to an issue of trying to handle the work within the request pipeline. When there's some long-running task to be completed or just some heavy work to be done, the first step should always be to pass it off to a background service. This allows you to return a response quickly. Web servers have a limited amount of threads to handle requests with, and you want to service the request and return a response as quickly as possible to keep from exhausting your threadpool.

You can use a library like Hangfire to handle your background work or you can implement an `IHostedService` [as described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.1#queued-background-tasks) to queue work on. Once you have your background service ready, you would then just immediately hand off to that any time your get a request to this endpoint, and return a `202 Accepted` response with a URL the client can hit to check the status. That solves your immediate issue of not wanting to allow a ton of requests to this long-running job to bring your API down. It's now essentially doing nothing more that just telling something else to do it and then returning immediately.

For the actual background work you'd be queuing, there, you can check the user's allowance and if they have exceeded 10 requests (your rate limit), you fail the job immediately, without doing anything. If not, then you can actually start the work.

If you like, you can also enable webhook support to notify the client when the job completes. You simply allow the client to set a callback URL that you should notify on completion, and then when you've finish the work in the background task, you hit that callback. It's on the client to handle things on their end to decide what happens when the callback is it. They might for instance decide to use SignalR to send out a message to their own users/clients.

**EDIT #2**

I actually got a little intrigued by this. While I still think it's better for your to offload the work to a background process, I was able to create a solution using `SemaphoreSlim`. Essentially you just gate every request through the semaphore, where you'll check the current user's remaining requests. This does mean that other users must wait for this check to complete, but then your can release the semaphore and actually do the work. That way, at least, you're not blocking other users during the actual long-running job.

First, add a field to whatever class you're doing this in:

```
private static readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
```

Then, in the method that's actually being called:

```
await _semaphore.WaitAsync();

// get remaining requests for user

if (remaining > 0)
{
    // decrement remaining requests for user (this must be done before this next line)

    _semaphore.Release();

    // now do the work
}
else
{
    _semaphore.Release();

    // handle user out of requests (return error, etc.)
}
```

This is essentially a bottle-neck. To do the appropriate check and decrementing, only one thread can go through the semaphore at a time. That means if your API gets slammed, requests will queue up and may take a while to complete. However, since this is probably just going to be something like a `SELECT` query followed by an `UPDATE` query, it shouldn't take that long for the semaphore to release. You should definitely do some load testing and watch it, though, if you're going to go this route.

Comment: The OP's question is an XY problem. There *are* ways of solving the actual problems, whatever that is. API request throttling, queueing, idempotent requests, Rx.NET buffering/throttling. Some work on standalone servers, some on farms

Comment: I suppose I was unclear. That's essentially what I meant. When I said I knew of no way to practically implement it, I meant specifically what the OP asked for in the question: creating a lock to literally stop any new request from being processed for the same user. I agree, the actual solution will need to be one of those you mentioned, and is certainly achievable in principle via those means.

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer, I was not sure if i was clear enough so I added an example